# How to loop over an array and insert the values of the array in a dynamically created HTML Table?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Using plain JavaScript and the dataset/ array below, I am trying to write a function that creates a table inside an HTML DIV.  EVERYTHING that is put inside the DIV must be generated by Javascript.I do not want to add the "CODE" values from the array in  to the table unless clicked. The array is below:

```
        var challenge_data = [];
        challenge_data[0] = [];
        challenge_data[0][0] = "CODE 1";
        challenge_data[0][1] = "DESCRIPTION 1";
        challenge_data[0][2] = "13256.45";
        challenge_data[1] = [];
        challenge_data[1][0] = "CODE 2";
        challenge_data[1][1] = "DESCRIPTION 2";
        challenge_data[1][2] = "244.78";
        challenge_data[2] = [];
        challenge_data[2][0] = "CODE 3";
        challenge_data[2][1] = "DESCRIPTION 3";
        challenge_data[2][2] = "1867.44";
        challenge_data[3] = [];
        challenge_data[3][0] = "CODE 4";
        challenge_data[3][1] = "DESCRIPTION 4";
        challenge_data[3][2] = "1455.55";
```

my solution which obviously did not create the same thing I wanted:

```
         document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        // get the reference for the body
          var body = document.getElementById("challenge_container_1");

          // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
          var tbl = document.createElement("table");
          var tbl1 = document.createElement("table");
          var tbl2 = document.createElement("table");
          var tbl3 = document.createElement("table");
          // var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

          // creating all cells
          for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            // creates a table row
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            var row1 = document.createElement("tr");
            var row2 = document.createElement("tr");
            var row3 = document.createElement("tr");

            for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
              // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
              // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
              // the end of the table row
              var cell = document.createElement("td");
              var cell1 = document.createElement("td1");
              var cell2 = document.createElement("td2");
              var cell3 = document.createElement("td3");
              var cell4 = document.createElement("td4");
              var cell5 = document.createElement("td5");
              var cell6 = document.createElement("td6");
              var cell7 = document.createElement("td7");

              var cellText = document.createTextNode(challenge_data[0][1]);
              var cellText1 = document.createTextNode(challenge_data[0][2]);
              var cellText2 = document.createTextNode(challenge_data[1][1]);
              var cellText3 = document.createTextNode(challenge_data[1][2]);
              var cellText4 = document.createTextNode(challenge_data[2][1]);
              var cellText5 = document.createTextNode(challenge_data[2][2]);
              var cellText6 = document.createTextNode(challenge_data[3][1]);
              var cellText7 = document.createTextNode(challenge_data[3][2]);

              cell.setAttribute("class", "tdclass" );
              cell1.setAttribute("class", "tdclass" );
              cell2.setAttribute("class", "tdclass" );
              cell3.setAttribute("class", "tdclass" );
              cell4.setAttribute("class", "tdclass" );
              cell5.setAttribute("class", "tdclass" );
              cell6.setAttribute("class", "tdclass" );
              cell7.setAttribute("class", "tdclass" );

              cell.appendChild(cellText);
              cell1.appendChild(cellText1);
              cell2.appendChild(cellText2);
              cell3.appendChild(cellText3);
              cell4.appendChild(cellText3);
              cell5.appendChild(cellText3);
              cell6.appendChild(cellText3);
              cell7.appendChild(cellText3);

              row.appendChild(cell, cell1);
              // row.appendChild(cell1);
              row1.appendChild(cell2, cell3);
              // row1.appendChild(cell3);
              row2.appendChild(cell4,cell5);
              // row2.appendChild(cell5);
              row3.appendChild(cell6, cell7);
              // row3.appendChild(cell7);

            }

            // add the row to the end of the table body
            // tblBody.appendChild(row, row1, row2, row3);
            row.setAttribute("class", "booclass" );
            row1.setAttribute("class", "booclass" );
            row2.setAttribute("class", "booclass" );
            row3.setAttribute("class", "booclass" );
          }

          // put the <tbody> in the <table>
          tbl.appendChild(row);
          tbl1.appendChild(row1);
          tbl2.appendChild(row2);
          tbl3.appendChild(row3);

          // appends <table> into <body>
          body.appendChild(tbl);
          body.appendChild(tbl1);
          body.appendChild(tbl2);
          body.appendChild(tbl3);
          // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
          tbl.setAttribute("class", "democlass" );
          tbl1.setAttribute("class", "democlass" );
          tbl2.setAttribute("class", "democlass" );
          tbl3.setAttribute("class", "democlass" );

        });
```

[image: The mockup for what I want the table to look like is below:]

Comment: Question: are you creating the array??... why you are not using an array of objects???

Comment: You'd save yourself a ton of repetitive code by using a templating engine

Comment: Let's say I did not want to use a templating engine and just create the table just using vanilla javascript.

Comment: Pato Salazar, it was a choice to make the array this way instead of "var challengeData = Array()" as an object

Comment: Definitely you are in wrong way, use template engines like [HandlebarsJS](http://handlebarsjs.com/), it's life saver. it's powerful and easy to use.

Comment: Mehdi Dehghani, thank you for the feedback. I understand how frameworks and template engines would make my life easier but the goal is here to figure out how to recreate the mockup using plain javascript, at least in my case.